# how to repeat this class?

Tags: c++, class, object, repeat

1. I want to ask the user to enter maximum 20 house details. I need to repeat my questions by number of house that user entered.
2. Then I want to show details in a list

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class House
{
      private :
             int NumRooms;
             int Area;
             int FloorNumber;
      public :

             void Getdata()
             {
                   cout << "Enter number of rooms in house: ";
                   cin >> NumRooms;
                   cout << "Enter area of house: ";
                   cin >> Area;
                   cout << "Enter floor number of house: ";
                   cin >> FloorNumber;
             }
             void Putdata()
             {
                   cout  << "Number of rooms: " << NumRooms << endl;
                   cout << "Area of house: " << Area << endl;
                   cout << "Floor number: " << FloorNumber << endl;
            }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    House s;
    s.Getdata();
    s.Putdata();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a loop? Store them in a `std::vector`?

Comment: @crashmstr that's crazy talk

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "Enter number of house you want to enter: ";
    int nhouses;
    cin >> nhouses;

    std::vector<House> houses;

    for (int i=0; i<nhouses; i++) {
        House s;
        s.Getdata();
        houses.push_back(s);
    }

    for (auto& hit = houses.begin(); hit != houses.end(); ++hit)
        hit->PutData();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

this actually supports any number of houses (more than 20). if you really want to limit the number to 20 just insert a

```
if (nhouses > 20) {
    std::cout << "more than 20? you are a horrible person" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I have to do it with class. I can't use for loop in class because getdata and putdata will be gone from being object

Answer (score 0):

I am newbie in c++ but by looking at your question it seems a bit vague but i will have a go at it anyways

1) how about declaring house s as an array
         house s[30];

```
    and taking the inputs inside a for loop??? or a do-while
```

Comment: Arrays can be evil, use `std::vector` instead.